# Unity 3D: For looping C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Code work properly, but i need to limiting the prefab to 5 times only.
I want to using for loop.....

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class theScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject prefab1;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("Instant_", 1f, 1f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void Instant_(){
        Instantiate (prefab1, transform.position, transform.rotation );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is there any reason for using 'for' statement?
How about this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class theScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject prefab1;
    public int FiveTimeCheck;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        FiveTimeCheck = 0;
        InvokeRepeating ("Instant_", 1f, 1f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void Instant_(){
        if(FiveTimeCheck <= 5)
        {
            FiveTimeCheck += 1;
            Instantiate (prefab1, transform.position, transform.rotation );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. It will be better uf you choose my anwser. :)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the functions like `Invoke` or `InvokeRepeating`. Since you refer to a function by its *name*, if you change it, the string in the Invoke call won't update. Moreover, The `Instant_` method will be called uselessly until you change scene or quit game with the method of @bismute.

I suggest you using coroutines. And bonus, you will use a foor loop ! ;D

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class theScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject prefab1;
    public int MaxInstantiation = 5;

    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine( InstantiatePrefab(1) ) ;
    }

    private IEnumerator InstantiatePrefab( float delay = 1f )
    {
        WaitForSeconds waitDelay = new WaitForSeconds( delay ) ;
        for( int instantiateCount = 0 ; instantiateCount < MaxInstantiation ; ++instantiateCount )
        {
            yield return waitDelay ;
            Instantiate (prefab1, transform.position, transform.rotation ) ;
        }
        yield return null ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but i am beginner and really need basic knowledge.

Comment: Coroutines are essential in Unity, and not that hard to understand ;)